# Multiple Scripts in 1 project, App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an App script project with several html files and 2 scripts(Code.gs, Utilities.gs). I want to be able to call functions from **Utilities.gs** in **Code.gs** but I dont know how to communicate between 2 scripts in one project. Is there a way to import/include scripts or something similar?

For example if I have a function called `getInfo()` in **Utilities.gs** I would like to call `getInfo()` in **Code.gs**. In java this would be `Utilities.getInfo()`

I dont see anything about this in the docs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to do anything, every function in every script files in the same project are accessible from any script file... the separation in script files is only a comfortable way to store things the way you want.  The project is the only "real" container.

Comment: ahh, awesome. One more thing, is there a limit to the number of methods a single script file can have? I have been having this issue where if I add one more function(empty or not), crashes my script. If I then "make space" for the new methord by commenting out an existing method, the script runs fine. This is a Container bound script(Spreadsheet)

Comment: And moving methods from 1 script to another does not solve the issue specified above

Comment: I never experienced such issue although some of my scripts are pretty long... how many functions do you have and how long is your script ? are you sure the issue is related to script size ?

Comment: Exactly 50 methods with 1321 lines of code. If I add one more method this thing will crash. I dont want to think it's the number of methods but seems like it.

Comment: I'm not aware of a size limit...as I said, I've never had such issue. I'd suggest you expose your issue on the issue tracker to get Googlers attention. In the mean time please consider accepting this answer :-) .

Comment: Thank you for your help and as you suggested posted an issue in the issue tracker, https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4210&thanks=4210&ts=1406115747